# Power and Energy of Periodic Signal

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, signal-processing

I have started learning digital signal processing and came across with a question about energy and power of a digial signal.

I have calculated the correct answers but i'm not quite sure about that i have done the calculations correctly, in other words, i may have solved them by luck. I tried finding similar questions on Youtube or on other websites but i couldn't. Could someone who has experience with solving that kind of problems have a quick look at my solution and suggest me a book ?

$$
x[n] =   \Bigg\{ (-1)^n.n, for \ n=1,2,3 \\ 0 \ otherwise 
$$

We also have its periodic version
$$
y\left[n\right]=\sum _{n=-\infty \:}^{\infty }\:x\left[n+7k\right]
$$

I'm supposed to calculate the energy and power of $x[n]$ and $y[n]$.

For  of $x[n]$
$$
E=\sum _{n=-\infty \:}^{\infty }\:\left|x\left[n\right]\right|^2=\left(\left|-1\right|+\left|2\right|+\left|-3\right|\right)^2=14
$$
$$
\lim \:_{n\to \:\:\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2N+1}\:\sum _{n=-N}^N\:\left|x\left[n\right]\right|^2\:\right)=\lim \:\:_{n\to \infty \:}\frac{1}{2N+1}\left[\sum _{n=-N}^0\left(0\right)\:+\sum _{n=1}^3\left(14\right)\:\sum _{n=4}^{\infty }\left(0\right)\:\right]=\lim \:\:\:_{n\to \:\infty \:\:}\frac{14}{2N+1}=0
$$

I think i have calculated $x[n]$ correctly yet the problem comes with periodic $y[n]$ function. Since it is periodic the energy will be equal to infinity because we will sum 14 to the last.

For power of $y[n]$ we have the formula below because it is periodic.
$$
P_x=\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}\:\left|x\left[n\right]\right|^2
$$
Since $y[n]$ is periodic we know that it is circulating, we also know that we will get the same values after every 7th iteration. Since energy of $x[n]=14$ and the sample size is 7. I thought we can get the answer as:

$$
P_x=\frac{1}{N}\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}\:\left|x\left[n\right]\right|^2=\frac{14}{7}=2
$$

The answers are correct but since i couldn't understand how to solve periodic discrete function (because of shifting). I'm not sure about the solution. I would appreciate that if someone enlighten me and provide me some sources.

Comment: The power for a periodic signal $y[n]$, of period $N$ samples, is defined as $(1/N)\sum_{n=n_0}^{n_0+N}|y[n]|^2$, with $n_0$ any integer number. For convenience, we usually set $n_0=0$, but you can verify by direct computation that the sum has the same value for any choice of $n_0$.